# Create a new column with a specific string in every row

Tags: r

In a dataframe

```
df <-  data.frame(id = c(12,35), col1 = c("ext", "another"))
```

How is it possible to add a new column which will contain in every row the same text

Example output

```
df <-  data.frame(id = c(12,35), col1 = c("ext", "another"), mycol = c("mytext","mytext"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it.

```
df <-  data.frame(id = c(12,35), col1 = c("ext", "another"))

df$mycol <-  "mytext"
# id    col1  mycol
# 1 12     ext mytext
# 2 35 another mytext
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also make use the recycling

```
data.frame(id = c(12,35), col1 = c("ext", "another"), mycol = "mytext")
```